# MacBook Pro Late 2011 replace headphone 3.5 mm jack due to headphone's head stuck inside jack

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

The headphone's tip has got stuck inside the 3.55 mm jack of my MacBook Pro late 2011 13 inch model. I've tried several ways to pry the head out, including using adhesive on a tip of a stick to get it out, but in vain.

Is there a way I can completely replace the 3.5 mm headphone jack socket/port?

I took it to an iStore, and the personnel there said that I'll have to replace the entire motherboard amounting to under 1000 US dollars.

The audio output shows as "Digital Out" and the audio icon is greyed out, I can't use headphones and the internal speakers don't work either.

I'm left with a MacBook Pro that's mute.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a USB output device, like a Griffin iMic. You can set the audio output in the Sound preferences panel to go to the iMic, then attach any speaker or Mic to that.

Comment: In the **"Select a device for sound output"**, there is only one option: **Name: Digital Output || Type: Optical Digital Out-put Port**. Under **"Settings for the selected device:** it says the **Selected device has no output controls** If I follow your advice and buy an USB to 3.5 mm jack adapter, will my MacBook Pro's audio options change automatically to reflect the new device's introduction? Or will it stay the same?

Comment: When you plug in a USB sound device, you will see it listed in the Sound Output options. But, since I don't have a way to simulate your problem, I can't say with 100% certainty. When I have no iMic plugged into my computer, there is no listing for it in the Sound prefs, but it will appear when I plug it in. It appears as a completely new output device.

Comment: It works this way. Thank you. It shows up as **Generic USB Audio Device** Type **USB**.